# How to convert JavaScript dictionary into Python syntax

Tags: javascript, python

Writing out `javascript` dictionary from inside of `JavaScript`- enabled application (such as Adobe)  into external .jsx file (using `dict.toSource()`) the context of resulted dictionary looks like:

```
({one:"1", two:"2"})
```

(Please note that dictionary keys are written as they are the variables name (which is not true).
A next step is to read this .jsx file with Python. I need to find a way to convert `({one:"1", two:"2"})` into Python dictionary syntax such as:

```
{'one':"1", 'two':"2"}
```

It has been already suggested that instead of using `JavaScript`'s built-in `dict.toSource()` it would make more sense to use `JSON` which would write a dictionary content in similar to `Python` syntax. But unfortunately using `JSON` is not an option for me. I need to find a way to convert `({one:"1", two:"2"})` into `{'one':"1", 'two':"2"}` using Python alone. Any suggestions on how to achieve it? Once again, the problem mostly in dictionary keys syntax which inside of Python look like variable names instead of strings-like dictionary keys names:

```
one vs "one"
```

## EDITED LATER:

Here is the content of the output.txt file as a result of `JavaScript` dictionary exported from inside of `JaveScript`. The goal is to read the content of output.txt file into Python and convert it to Python dictionary.
Please keep in mind that the dictionary is only here that simple. In real world scenario it will be a MegaByte long with many nested keys/values.

Once again, the content of output.txt:

```
({one:"1", two:"2"})
```

We need to transform it into Python syntax dictionary (it is fine if we use JSON if it is used in Python):

```
{'one':'1', 'two':'2'}
```

Comment: Why can't you output your data as JSON?  It would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Python has a JSON library. It is a built-in, you don't have to find it. Try `import json`

Comment: `{'one':"1", 'two':"2"}` is valid as either a Python Dict or a Javascript Object.

Comment: @Surreal: Adobe application that writes `JavaScript` dictionary out to the file supports `JavaScript`. It does not support `JSON`. Sure, `JSON` module can be copied to /This App/script/ folder. But that would have to be repeated on each and every machine running this app. It is exactly what I want to avoid. By all mean the code should be kept all "stock". No plugin, addons or module outside of default install please. It was mentioned `JSON` cannot be used as a solution. Why to re-ask it again?  The solution can be found using stock `JavaScript` or stock `Python`. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Paul: Did you read my question? `dict.toSource()` writes out the dictionary keys as names of the variables such as {me: 'not reading', question: 'carefully enough', to:'really understand it'}. If such dict read by `Python` it assumes `me`, `question` and `to` are all pre-declared variables. If if think the solution could be found with `JSON` module in Python please feel free to share how it could be all accomplished. Thanks again!

Comment: @Downvoters: a reason? What is a reason? Do you have an answer? I don't see any posted yet. You can't answer the question. And yet you find it it deserves a downvote. Wtf?

Comment: [demjson](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/) in non-strict mode could probably do it if you slice off the parentheses first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With trivial objects containing no enclosed objects**, this is a basic string manipulation problem.

As soon as you have a compound object, the code I'll show you will fail.

Let's fire up Python 2.7 and use your example string:

`>>> x='({one:"1", two:"2"})'`

Now what you want is a dict d...

What do we know about dict?

Well, a dict can be made from a list of (key, value) "2-ples", by which I mean a list of two element lists as opposed to a list of python tuple read-only lists.

Each tuple is a representation of a property like `one:"1"`

First, we need to reduce x to a substring that contains the desired information.

Clearly the parenthesis and brackets are superfluous, so we can write:

```
>>> left = x.find("{")
>>> right = x.find("}")
>>> y = x[left+1:right]
```

Here, the `String.find()` method finds the first index of the search string parameter.

The notation `x[n:m]` is a substring of the n-th through the m-1st character of x, inclusive.

Obtaining:

```
>>> y
'one:"1", two:"2"'
```

That's just a string, not a tuple, but it can be made a tuple if we split on comma.

```
>>> z = y.split(",")
```

Obtaining:

```
>>> z
['one:"1"', ' two:"2"']
```

Now each of these strings represents a property, and we need to tease out the key and value.

We can use a [list comprehension (see tutorial 5.1.4 if unfamiliar)](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to do that.

```
>>> zz = [ (s[0:s.find(":")].strip(),s[s.find('"')+1:-1].strip()) for s in z]
```

Where once again we use `find()` to get the indexes of the colon and quote.

Here we also use strip() to strip out the whitespace that will otherwise creep in.

This step obtains:

```
>>> zz
[('one', '1'), ('two', '2')]
```

Which is almost what we wanted.

Now just

> > > d = dict(zz)

And it is done!

```
>>> d
{'two': '2', 'one': '1'}
```

Note that dict does not preserve the order of keys.

Comment: From dict all the way down to string and then back to dict again. At least we didn't not have to deal with a machine language of zeros and ones to solved it. Thanks for educating me.

Comment: Careful.  `x` is just a string.  It can't be a dict, because, as you noticed, it is in the wrong format for python to accept it as a dict.

Comment: This is only sufficient for very, very simple Javascript objects. There are plenty of ways this can go wrong. Nested objects, braces in strings, and other unanticipated cases will cause this code to fail.

Comment: Yes, probably.  There were answers by others earlier, involving the python `json` built in module, that might have been more robust. OP didn't want that or something happened.  When I came back those answers were deleted.  Some of the question comments may be insightful.

Comment: No, I am fine with`JSON` if it is used from inside of `Python` to read the dictionary in (since Python supports `JSON` natively. Please outline how it could be achieved from inside Python. If let's say I have a text file as a result of 'JaveScript` dictionary export... How do I use `JSON` module in Python to read `JavaScript` exported dictionary into Python: Once again here is how `JavaScript` writes to output (export) file using myDict.toSource(): `({one:"1", two:"2"})` The main problem is that dictionary keys don't have quotes characters making them (the dict keys) appear like variables name

Comment: Since those answers are no longer here and were posted by others, it is difficult to critique them.  Also, to use the json module you would need to "repair" the keys since python's `json.loads()` also requires keys to have quotes.

Comment: The dictionary arriving from `JavaScript` is going to be nested three/four/five levels down. And it is going to be a massive one. It could be a page long easily. Not human readable for sure. I need one robust reliable way to get that `JavaScript` dictionary adopted by Python. I can't believe it can't be done without using "perfocard" methods.

Comment: @Sputnix Are you absolutely certain that `JSON.stringify(dict)` won't work in Adobe's implementation of Javascript?  If it is old, well, ok.  But nodeJS and all modern web browsers have a JSON.stringify() function builtin without loading anything extra.

Comment: Here's the thing, if JSON doesn't work, and my code is unsuited for your actual purpose, then you may ultimately be left with parsing one character at a time and/or hacking on the source code of the python json library.

Comment: JSON is not implemented in Adobe CS6 products (I am not sure about CC yet).

Comment: Your code is pretty cool. I just want to make sure we reviewed every possible solution for this.

Comment: @user2357112 An edit to the first line of my answer was made in bold to address your comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[One of the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966078/how-to-convert-javascript-dictionary-into-python-syntax#comment36927178_23966078) suggested using [demjson](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/docs). This does indeed work and seems a better solution.

```
import demjson
demjson.decode('{one:"1", two:"2"}')
```

Outputs:

```
{u'two': u'2', u'one': u'1'}
```

Comment: +1 A lot more robust and would probably solve the parsing problem.  OP had some restrictions about external libraries, though.

Comment: I can't see any mention of restriction on external python libraries. I thought the restriction was just on the JS side. If the OP can't install libraries they can simply copy the source https://github.com/dmeranda/demjson/blob/master/demjson.py

Answer (score 0):

While working in `JavaScript` I've noticed that its built-in `.toSource()` method will write key dictionary properly enclosed in quotes `"`dict key name`"` if that dictionary key includes a non-letter character in its name such as a white space, comma, period, a dollar sign and etc. Example:

Example `JavaScript`:

```
var dictVar = {'one':'1','.two':'2', 'three,':3, 'fo ur':4,"five":"five"};
mySaveFile = new File('/my/path/to/JavaDictToPython.txt');    
mySaveFile.open("w","TEXT","????");
mySaveFile.write(dictVar.toSource());
mySaveFile.close();
```

A dictionary will be written to file as:

```
({one:"1", ".two":"2", "three,":3, "fo ur":4, five:"five"})
```